# pgadmin: can't insert jsonb[] values with strings

Tags: postgresql, json, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have `jsonb[]` column and it allows me to insert some nested arrays, but only with number values like `{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}`. I'm not talking about inserting some nested objects like `{{"one": "two"}, {"three": "four"}}`.

How to even insert nested string values like:

```
{ {"one", "two", "three"},
  {"four", "five", "six"},
  {"seven", "eight", "nine"} }
```

[image]

**ERROR: invalid syntax..., token "one" invalid**

Comment: For arrays, you have to use square brachets `[ ... ]`, not braces `{ ... }`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no, I haven't to. Postgres require curly brackets for array annotation.

Comment: I misread. But the array elements are `jsomb` arrays, so *they* have to be surrounded by brackets (and quoted, as in `{"[1,2,3]","[4,5,6]"}`) .

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: in **pgadmin** you have to escape every quotation mark before and after key/value definition.
What a sophisticated solution.

```
{
    "{\"one\": \"two\"}",
    "{\"three\": \"foure\"}",
    "{\"fivep\": \"six\"}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your json data format is invalid, you can check it first with some IDE / online tools like [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/) :

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>   {   {       "one",      "two",
>   --^
>   Expecting 'STRING', '}', got '{'

Even {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}} has invalid json format.

it should be run with this data :

```
{   "a": [1, 2, 3],     "b": [4, 5, 6],     "c": [7, 8, 9] }
```

OR :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

and this :

```
{   "a": ["one", "two", "three"],   "b": ["four", "five", "six"],   "c": ["seven", "eight", "nine"] }
```

OR

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
```